# デストラクタを呼ぶテンプレート関数でデータ型を指定すると何故かエラーにならず処理が通ってしまいます。

Tags: c++

偶然みつけたものですが、引数オブジェクトのデストラクタを呼ぶテンプレート関数で
データ型を指定するとなぜかエラーにならず、そのまま処理が通ってしまいますが何故でしょうか？
また処理が通ってしまうことでバグの原因に繋がるでしょうか？
Visual Studio2019を使用しています。

```
// main.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

// コンストラクタ、デストラクタで文字出力するだけのクラス
class Dummy {
public:
    Dummy() { printf("Dummy();\n"); }
    virtual ~Dummy() { printf("~Dummy()\n"); }
};

// デストラクタだけを呼ぶテンプレート関数
template <typename T>
void Foo(T* _pPtr)
{
    _pPtr->~T();
}

// メイン関数
int main()
{
    {
        // 問題なくコンストラクタ、デストラクタが呼ばれる。
        void* _pAlloc = malloc(sizeof(Dummy));
        Dummy* _pObj = new(_pAlloc) Dummy;
        Foo(_pObj);
        free(_pAlloc);
    }
    {
        // データ型を指定すると、エラーにならずに処理が通ってしまう。
        void* _pAlloc = malloc(sizeof(float));
        float* _pObj = new(_pAlloc) float;
        Foo(_pObj);
        free(_pAlloc);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 「データ型」が何を指し、何を問題視しているかわかりませんでした。`float`のコンストラクター＆デストラクターを呼び出せることを気にされているのでしょうか？

Comment: どのようなエラーになると考えているか、あるいはそう判断した基になる資料などはありますか？ こんな感じで。[C++ で明示的にデストラクタを呼び出す](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/cpp/call-destructor-in-cpp/), [C++ でチルダ演算子を使用したクラス・デストラクタの定義](https://www.delftstack.com/ja/howto/cpp/cpp-tilde-operator/), [コンストラクタとデストラクタ](https://yttm-work.jp/lang/cpp/cpp_0003.html), [virtualデストラクタ](https://yttm-work.jp/lang/cpp/cpp_0012.html), [C++入門者に贈るclass入門とclass/structキーワードの使い分け](https://qiita.com/yumetodo/items/b0ff58617f2733d4ffa1), [テンプレートとデストラクタ](https://www.akamoz.jp/you/uni/templ-dtor.htm)

Comment: 正しい用語を使わないと誤解を招くので、「組み込み型」(built-in types) や「基本型」(fundamental types) と呼ぶべきだと思います。[Built-in types (C++) | Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/fundamental-types-cpp), [Fundamental types - cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

Comment: マルチポスト先で解決しているようですね。[C++のテンプレート関数から...](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q14246487449)

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローではマルチポスト自体は禁止されていませんが、最低限のマナーは守ってください。「[マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？ - スタック・オーバーフローMeta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2418)」

Answer (score 4, accepted):

結論から言うと、 C++ の規格に明記された挙動なので、問題ありません。

C++11 (N3337) の標準規格の [`12.4 Destructors p16`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/class.dtor#16) に以下のように書かれています。

> the notation for explicit call of a destructor can be used for any scalar type name ([expr.pseudo]). Allowing this makes it possible to write code without having to know if a destructor exists for a given type. For example,
> 参考訳: スカラの型名に対して、デストラクタの明示的な呼出しの記法を使うことができる ([expr.pseudo]) 。それを許すことによって、型に対するデストラクタがあるか否かを知らなくても、コードを書くことができる。例えば：
> For example:
>
> ```cpp
> typedef int I;
> I* p;
> p->I::~I();
> ```

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456310/destructors-of-builtin-types-int-char-etc

この、スカラ型（厳密には、クラスではない型）に対する呼び出しは、「疑似デストラクタ」と呼ばれていて、 その挙動は [`5.2.4 Pseudo destructor call`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.pseudo#1) で定義されています。
具体的には、 `p` が評価される以外の効果は発生しません。
また、ドット演算子の左辺はスカラ型、アロー演算子の左辺はスカラ型へのポインタでなけれなりません。

上記の例にあるように、テンプレートを使わずとも、 typedef で組み込み型のキーワードに別名をつければ、明示的に呼び出すことが可能です。
`_pObj->~float();` とするとエラーになってしまう (※) のは、 float 型がスカラ型であるからではなく、 `float` が識別子ではない（キーワードである）からでしょうね。
※: g++ (GNU C++ Compiler) ではエラーになりましたが、コンパイラーによってはエラーにならないかもしれません。

なお、ここで言うスカラ型というのは、 [`3.9 Types p9`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.types#9) で定義されている、算術型・列挙型・ポインタ型・メンバへのポインタ型 を指します。
つまり、（構造体を含む）クラス型やスカラ型以外のもの、例えば配列型などでは、明示的なデストラクタの呼び出しの記述が行えません。

```cpp
#include <iostream>
typedef int I;
typedef int A[3];

int main() {
    I i = 1;
    i.~I();
    // ↑ これは可能

    A a = { 0, 1, 2 };
    a.~A();
    // ↑ これはエラー
}
```

---

ちなみに、 C++03 (N1577) でも、 `12.4 デストラクタ p15` で同様の内容が記載されています。
C++03 であれば、対応する JIS規格 ([JISX3014](https://www.jisc.go.jp/app/jis/general/GnrJISNumberNameSearchList?show&jisStdNo=X3014)) が存在するので、日本語でその内容を確認できます。